# How to compare NSString having " sign?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I am trying to do like this, but it gives error as `"` is present.

```
if (!([post.videoID isEqualToString:@"<null>"])) {
```

How can I compare such string which contains " with it?

Comment: Use [Escape Sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15387756/1603072).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid way to check null

```
if (!([post.videoID isEqual:[NSNull null]]))
{
}
```

And this is your solution...

```
if (!([post.videoID isEqualToString:@"\"<null>\""]))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always remember to put `\` as escape sequence when there is a `"` available in the code.

```
if (!([post.videoID isEqualToString:@"\"<null>\""])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check with [NSNull null] object.

```
if (!([post.videoID isEqual:[NSNull null]])) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *p=@"\"";
    if ([p isEqualToString:@"\""]) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy this

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"",post.videoID ];
if (!([str isEqualToString:@"\"<null>\""])) {}
```